# Nautilus in Ubuntu 16.04: How to show bookmark without all devices?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

I would like to have my Nautilus a little more clean... I have two hard disk drive and some shared network places mapped at my PC, I have just add some bookmarks but I was not able to remove the "devices" from sidebar in Nautilus.

Is this change possible to do? I would like to have only the "computer" icon in the devices tab.

[image: nautilus_view]

Ubuntu 16.04